# Chrome crashed with private tabs/windows

Tags: google-chrome, history

I had many incognito tabs and windows open in Chrome. My mac crashed, and I restarted it manually by button.

When the programs opened back up, Chrome showed a yellow notification bar asking to restore items. I accidentally clicked away.

I tried looking through the last session file which doesn't appear to have the history in it.

I also tried setting `"exited_cleanly":false` in local state. I looked up the DNS cache but it only showed the last hour of activity in the console.

Have I forever lost these tabs/windows? Is there a network log for Mac OS X? Perhaps my router logs websites? Or my cable modem? I searched around but no luck.

Comment: If you didn't restore the incognito then you are out of luck.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

One of the features of incognito mode
is that it doesn't keep any records of what you do. 
Therefore, when your machine crashes, there is nothing to restore.

Answer (score 1):

Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs, which implies that anything in **incognito mode** is it self-destructs history on browser close, erasing all the tracked browsing. But any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.

Therefore the moment your computer crashes, every browser’s history, cookie store, or search history will be destroyed as well.

Which means:

> - Chrome won't save your browsing history, cookies and site data, or information entered in forms.
> - Files you download and bookmarks you create will be kept.
> - Your activity isn’t hidden from websites you visit, your employer or school, or your internet service provider.

[Google](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7440301) has an article on this that you might want to check.

Comment: A network device might have logged the browsing history but nothing can be confirmed based on what the question author provided